# Youtube analytics api, for other channels

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-api

Wonder if there is an option to get statistics for channels in youtube that i dont own.

Example is i want to know number of view for a spesific channel during last month vs the month before.

I am using v3 youtybe api.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do this because there is an Oauth authentication which validates your account. Even if you know someone's channel id, still there is a verification that will happen to your request.

> To retrieve a channel report, you must set the ids parameter value in your API request to one of the following values:
>
> **channel==MINE** – The API returns data for the authenticated user's YouTube channel.
>
> **channel==CHANNEL_ID** – Set CHANNEL_ID to the unique channel ID of the channel for which you are retrieving data. **The user authorizing the request must be the owner of the channel.**
>
> The channel ID is currently a string that begins with the letters UC, though its format is subject to change. (You can find your channel's ID on the advanced account settings page for your YouTube channel, or you can retrieve your channel's ID programmatically using the YouTube Data API's channels.list method.)
>
> Please see this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports) for more information.

You can also try a sample request using the [Try it] section in this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/data_model).

Hope this one will help.

Comment: Ok thanks, so let me ask my question differently, how can i retrieve likes per channel or movie over time? Is this possible?

Comment: You can specify in your request a date range, metrics (likes, views, etc.), and id (channel id). Note that these are the required fields.
Here's sample request after I use the [Try it] section link above: 

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=Q5mHPo2yDG8&start-date=2016-01-01&end-date=2016-02-01&metrics=likes&key={YOUR_API_KEY} 

Please also refer to this guide:
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/data_model

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests#channel-time-based-reports

Comment: `you cannot do this because there is an OAuth authentication which validates your account`   this judgment is fundamentally incorrect,  some  API need OAuth authentication but you could still view stats that don't belong to something you own.